Keycloak-Angular Error by calling keycloak.init()
I am using the newest Keycloak Version with Angular 18. When calling keycloak.init i am getting follwoing error:
ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined at Keycloak

My Code is looking like this:
export class AppComponent {
  title = '$title';

  constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('App Component initialized!');
    this.initializeKeycloak();
  }
  private initializeKeycloak(): void {
  console.log('Initializing Keycloak...');
  try {
    this.keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: '$keycloak_url',
        realm: '$my_realm',
        clientId: '$myClient',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        flow: 'standard',
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Keycloak:', error);
  }
}
}

The Login and Redirection to my App is working fine but I am still getting that error. Does anyone know what to do?
I already tried to import DOCUMENT from '@angular/common' but that also doesnt help.

do you have this error during server side rendering?

Keycloak.js is currently available for the client-side because of the usage of iframe

I think SSR is turned on, so you need to run this code only on client, for this we can use the isPlatformBrowser to make the code run only on the browser (Where document and window exist) and possibly solve your issue.
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
...

...
export class AppComponent {
  title = '$title';

  constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakService, 
      @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
            this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('App Component initialized!');
    if(this.isBrowser) {
        this.initializeKeycloak();
    }
  }
  ...

